# Not able to make Powershell script upload part of the file with Autodesk Forge API

Tags: powershell, autodesk-forge

I have this python code that uploads part of the file to the server

```
import requests

file_path = "/Downloads/bim/7_LARD_90_99.ifc"
range_start = 0
range_end = 299999

headers = {
    "X-API-KEY": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; filename=7_LARD_90_99.ifc",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "Content-Range": f"bytes {range_start}-{range_end}/16531527"
}

try:
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        file_chunk = file.read(range_end - range_start + 1)

    response = requests.post(
        "https://field.dalux.com/service/api/1.0/projects/xxxxxxxx/file_areas/yyyyyyyy/upload/zzzzzzzzzz",
        headers=headers,
        data=file_chunk
    )

    print("Response Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response Content:", response.text)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
```

This code works fine. I am trying to convert it to Powershell, but it seems that Powershell handles differently requests and it shows different size of the body (which throws exception on the API).

```
$file = "/Downloads/bim/7_LARD_90_99.ifc"
$rangeStart = 0
$rangeEnd = 299999

$headers = @{
    "X-API-KEY" = "xxx-xxx-xxx"
    "Content-Disposition" = "form-data; filename=7_LARD_90_99.ifc"
    "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream"
    "Content-Range" = "bytes $rangeStart-$rangeEnd/16531527"
}

try {
    $fileChunkBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)[$rangeStart..$rangeEnd]
    Write-Host $fileChunkBytes.Length

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post `
        -Uri "https://field.dalux.com/service/api/1.0/projects/xxxxxxx/file_areas/yyyyyyy/upload/zzzzzzzzz" `
        -Headers $headers `
        -ContentType "application/octet-stream" `
        -Body $fileChunkBytes `
        -UseBasicParsing

    Write-Host "Response Status Code: $($response.StatusCode)"
    Write-Host "Response Content:"
    $response.Content
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
}
```

I am getting this error from the API:

```
{

  "httpStatusCode": 400,

  "errorCode": "E40004",

  "errorCodeMessage": "HeaderValidationFailed",

  "message": "Content-Range header size 300000 is not the same as the content size 901216",

  "logTime": "2024-02-08T16:02:46.3439873Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was in Invoke-RestMethod method.

The parsing of the file chunk was problematic. Instead I made it working with WebRequest

```
        $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($filePath)
        $contentLength = $fileStream.Length
        
        $position = 0

        # Calculate the size of the next chunk
        $chunkSize = [Math]::Min($chunk_size, $contentLength - $position)

        # Read the next chunk from the file
        $chunkBytes = New-Object byte[] $chunkSize
        $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($chunkBytes, 0, $chunkSize)

        # Define the headers for the HTTP request
        $headersUpload = @{
            "X-API-KEY" = $apiKey
            "Content-Disposition" = "form-data; filename=$fileName"
            "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream"
            "Content-Range" = "bytes $position-$($position + $bytesRead - 1)/$contentLength"
            "Content-Length" = $bytesRead
        }

        # Create a WebRequest object
        $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri)
        $webRequest.Method = "POST"
        foreach ($key in $headersUpload.Keys) {
            $webRequest.Headers.Add($key, $headersUpload[$key])
        }
        # Get the request stream
        $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
        # Write the chunk to the request stream
        $requestStream.Write($chunkBytes, 0, $bytesRead)
        # Close the request stream
        $requestStream.Close()

        # Get the response
        $response = $webRequest.GetResponse()
        $response.Close()
```